# Configure Putty to send Telnet data without pressing Enter?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, putty, telnet

Is there a way to configure **Putty in telnet** mode to send data from the keyboard immediately, without having to press enter?

For example, when using Windows telnet, if i connect to my server and press the letter 'a' key, my server responds and shows that I pressed that.

When using telnet with Putty, if I press the 'a' key - **the same server** does nothing. Then when i press Enter, it shows I pressed the letter 'a'.

How can I configure Putty telnet to behave the same as Windows telnet? I saw something in general about this concept and removing  "linemode" but don't see any option for that?

Thanks.

Comment: What server is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Terminal -> Local line editing. When "local line editing" is on, PuTTY will let you edit the entire line locally and will only send it on a press of Enter. When it is turned off, you will get an immediate sending or each key press - though this is currently the default.

Comment: As noted by @lode, the default for "Local line editing" is "auto". According to the docs (https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter4.html#config-localedit), "auto" means that the actual configuration is selected automatically by PuTTY depending on the session protocol. The manual does not explain how the detection algorithm works, but I'm going to assume that it is "off" for SSH (which is what I normally use) and "on" for telnet.